# Could a local port be used to connect to multiple remote peers over UDP?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

With `connect(int socket, const struct sockaddr *address, socklen_t address_len);`, according to `man 2 connect`:

> The parameter socket is a socket. If it is of type SOCK_DGRAM, this call specifies the peer with which
>   the socket is to be associated; this address is that to which
>   datagrams are to be sent, and the only address from which datagrams
>   are to be received.

Does that mean a local port could still be used to connect to several remote peers over UDP? Or is it that one local port could only be used to connect to one peer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call connect() on your UDP socket, then you can only use it to send and receive packets to/from the address you passed in to connect().

However, if you do not call connect() on the UDP socket, you can use sendto() and recvfrom() to send/receive packets to/from multiple destinations using just that one socket.

Comment: Why is this the case? What extra does `connect()` do such that it needs to lock-in to the specific peer?

Comment: That's just how it works -- on a UDP socket, all connect() does is set a field in the socket's in-kernel data structure that tells the kernel to reject any incoming packets that are not marked as coming from that IP address, and to send a packet to that IP address when send() is called on the socket.  As to why it was implemented that way, I can only guess -- probably it was an attempt to allow the same code (that calls send() and recv()) to work as similarly as possible for either a TCP or UDP socket.

Comment: @Kate UDP is a connectionless protocol. The sockets api tries to be "helpful" and mimic a connection. The `connect()` api used on a UDP socket is IMHO an abomination. It fools you into believing something that isn't true.

Comment: UDP makes the initial handshake over a 'well known' use port.  Part of the initial handshake is to pass an alternate port number for the actual communication.

Comment: @user3629249 UDP itself doesn't do any handshaking.  The user's program might implement some sort of handshaking protocol on top of UDP if it chooses to, but the UDP layer itself is very simple and only sends a packet when the user's program calls send().